# setting up debian bullseye repository WITHOUT a CDN

Tags: debian, cdn

i have some debian boxes in a DMZ behind a restrictive firewall.
The problem is that those boxes are mostly not able to reach the CDN backed org.debian.org-repositories as the IP of deb.debian.org changes ramdomly and therefore the IP the boxes try to reach and the IPs that are allowed by the firewall are not the same.

I need to change the sources.list to not use deb.debian.org but e.g. ftp2.de.debian.org.

Well, that's fine working EXCEPT the security updates. It seems that there is just no debian-security subfolder available.
How to have a working sources.list?

my sources.list

```
deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
```

results in

```
root@MyHost:/home/MyUser# apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
Hit:1 http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: 137.226.34.46 80]
Hit:5 https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:6 https://download.jitsi.org stable/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i found a reason thanks to https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=85342

There are not many debisn-asecurity mirros. Seems most mirrors don't include that.

But using http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security  works.

Comment: Thank you... I have to setup a Debian environment in a very restricted network in the next few weeks too. You saved me a lot of work :-)